# how to fix this error "Error response from daemon : failed to parse Dockerfile : file with no instruction

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I would like to deploy spring boot project with jenkins, docker.
I installed jenkins on ubuntu `20`.(on a ec2 server). (it is not docker container)

here is my Dockerfile in spring boot project :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "/app.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

here is jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
              stage('Prepare') {
     steps {
                sh 'echo "Clonning Repository"'
                git branch: 'dev',
                    url: 'mygitlabUrl',
                    credentialsId: 'myappId'
            }
            post {
                success { 
                     sh 'echo "Successfully Cloned Repository"'
                 }
                 failure {
                     sh 'echo "Fail Cloned Repository"'
                 }
            }


        }
        
        stage('Bulid Gradle'){
             steps{
                dir('backend'){
                sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
                sh  './gradlew clean build'
                }
                }
             post {
                success {
                    echo 'gradle build success'
                }
                failure {
                    echo 'gradle build failed'
                }
            }
   

        }
                
        stage('Bulid Docker'){
            steps{
                script{
                sh 'echo " Image Bulid Start"'
                 docker.withRegistry('myDockerHubUrl','credentialId'){
                image = docker.build("DockerImageName")
                image.push()
                }

                 }



            }
            post {
                 failure {
                     sh 'echo "Bulid Docker Fail"'
                }
            }
        } 
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well I couldn't complete deploy code yet. My problem is in building the Docker Image.

Actually, my final goal is to deploy some Docker containers (including this) using pipelining.

I have no idea how to write `Dockerfile` and `Jenkinsfile` (or just pipeline script).

Comment: Welcome so StackOverflow. this not a good question...Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What problem are you running into?  Can you `docker build` the image outside of Jenkins?  Can you reduce the Jenkins Groovy pipeline code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @Ali oh sorry! I am not used to write posts here. thank you for advice. how can I mention you..

Comment: @DavidMaze oh actually I figured it out. and another problem when I execute docker container with jenkins, it stopped.
`docker.image('DockerImageName').withRun(' --rm -p 8080:8080'){}`